# left join only one column which is not the key and based on a condition

Tags: mysql

table_event(xman_id, event1,event2...) with 200,000 rows

table_link(xman_id,a_id) with only 10,000 rows

I want a new table have all the 100,000 rows appeared on table link and have all the value appeared on table event and the column names a_id only appeared on table_link. Hope can get a good answer thanks a lot, here is my code.

```
INSERT INTO newtable
select table_event*, table_link.a_id
FROM table_event LEFT JOIN table_link.a_id
     ON table_event.xman_id = table_link.xman_id;
```

the newtable is design as

xman_id, event1,event2... a_id

Comment: whats the issue with above query can you explain

Comment: Can you explain your question a different way? We cannot help you if we don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INNER JOIN` if you just want data in `table_link`.

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT table_event.*, table_link.a_id
FROM table_event
INNER JOIN table_link.a_id ON table_event.xman_id = table_link.xman_id;
```

This will just insert data into `newtable` with data only matched in both `table_event` and `table_link`.

And if you want all data in `table_link` to `newtable`, you should tell us what relation between `table_link` and `table_event` is, `one to many` or `one to one`.

If it's `one to many`, you should specify which row in `table_event` should be inserted into `newtable`.

If it's `one to one`, you can try following;

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT table_event.*, table_link.a_id
FROM table_link
LEFT JOIN table_event.a_id ON table_event.xman_id = table_link.xman_id;
```

Maybe there is null value which inserted into `newtable`.